# get my facebook album photos in android/java

Tags: android, facebook

is there any other/easy way to get the my facebook albums photos .
i have used the following way to get the photos from album.
is there any way to get access token through coding/programetically? write now i get it from browser......

### to get Access Token:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=223643860987514%2Fphotos

### to get album id:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=

### to get photo from perticular album:

https://graph.facebook.com/223643860987514/photos?access_token=

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: thanks for your comment , try to improve it

Comment: each time you have commit for improvement but not. why?

Comment: actually i don't before you have comments that if response from other users and is useful for me than accept it.....

Comment: but without improving, user will dislike to give answer

Comment: Ok Thanks for your suggestion.
from now onwords i'll take care of it and if any post/things that are useful for others than definitely ask the question and solution for that...

Comment: Hey nik, how to share something that is useful? i posted one code but because of it is not in well formatted,users gives negative response.

Comment: if your format is going to bad then user will correct it and he is not give you down vote becase this is general problem but if you ask non-programming related question or duplicated question or your elaboration are very poor or logically wrong in question so it will appear for downvote

Comment: now tell me which question you like to post and user give DV

Comment: your right i have posted duplicated question that's why user give DV.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480270/asynctask-also-in-flash  this is only elaboration but user like it so it give me +1

Comment: see also this ::: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481025/explaining-differece-between-aggregation-and-composition-aggregation-by-implemen

Comment: one more thing is that you cant asking to code directly but in your word you can indirectly tell them.

Comment: ok. thanks for your guidance and take care of these things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3607/discussion-between-hiren-dabhi-and-nik)

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve albums from the current Facebook SDK (4) you can do this:

```
   new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/albums",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    String albumID = null;
                    try{
                        JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                        JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject oneAlbum = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //get albums id
                            if (oneAlbum.getString("name").equals("Profile Pictures")) {
                                albumID = oneAlbum.getString("id");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        ).execAsyncTask();
```

The example retrieves the profile pictures album. After you get this album you can use the album id to retrieve the pictures.

Comment: how to get all pictures which are in album ?