# AsyncTask also in flash?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, air

i have develop one game size of 27mb,i load it in device & its performance are going to lower and some time its hang the device.there are much Media resource are  used in this game.if i make it in android then i will handle with [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and make some process in background and also make memory management but here i have develop game in flash with `AS3` and use `Adobe Air`. so my question is :: is there any method like asynTask are stay in flash or any performance related thing by which i take precaution against poor performance?

Thanks
 nik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using Flash 11 and AIR 3 - the new version allow the execution of native code, so that you can use Flash and AIR for the UI and the animations while at the same time you can execute asynchronously some native threaded code that otherwise would have of been occupying the time in between frames. In the native code you can have all of the calculations that are not related to the UI - e.g. the AI logic.

A detailed tutorial is provided by Lee Brimelow on his blog - [Two-Part Tutorial on Android Native Extensions](http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3049)

Comment: can you please give single example? +1

Comment: Adobe had published a tutorial article: [Extending Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html). It's quite recent - from Sep 06 2011. I still hadn't the time to get my hands dirty...soon

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's only two threads network thread and thread doing all other actions. 
Asynctask is about optimal using UI thread, so because of there's no separate UI thread in flash/AIR there could be no analogous tricks. As for other methods, I'm affraid there's no general answer.

Comment: can you provide some link or example? +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load assets asynchronously, you should use the URLLoader and Loader classes to load resources. They will load stuff in the background and throw an Event (Event.COMPLETE) when they are done.

Comment: can you provide some link or example? +1

Comment: Here's a link with a basic example: http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/11/load-external-swf-in-as3.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links on how to use PixelBender to do stuff like number crunching in a separate thread, I'm not sure it is supported on Android though, so you would have to look in to that further:

http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html

Stack Overflow question, the answer by Ascension Systems:

[Flash parallel programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606195/flash-parallel-programming/5606272#5606272)

Answer (score 0):

You should read **Optmizing performance for the Flash Platform** 
[help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/flashplatform_optimizing_content.pdf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/flashplatform_optimizing_content.pdf)